# Does multiplying by $i=\sqrt{-1}$ count as multiplying by a constant for the purposes of linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra

E.g. are $i \sin(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ linearly independent or linearly dependent?

For context, I'm trying to reconcile the $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ formula with the generalized solution to a homogeneous DE, $y=C_1e^{ax}\cos(bx) +C_2e^{ax}\sin(bx)$ and I think I'm just getting a bit confused.

Comment: "linearly independent" on what vector space?

Comment: "linearly independent" over what field?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the ground field: $\sin(x)$ and $i\sin(x)$ are:

- linearly dependent over $\Bbb C$;
- linearly independent over $\Bbb R$

Comment: How do you multiply by $i$ in $\mathbb{R}$? It's pretty clear that the constant field **must** be $\mathbb{C}$, we're not doing any formal variables here.

Comment: I'm considering, in both cases, the space of functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$.

Comment: Okay, that's technically possible but a little tortured in my book. On the one hand, you're solving a real DE and therefore restricting to domain $\mathbb{R}$, on the other hand you're ignoring that this is a real DE and allowing the range to be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Note that the formula $y=C_1e^{ax}\cos(bx) +C_2e^{ax}\sin(bx)$ refers to *real* second order linear differential equation and the coefficients $C_1,C_2$ belong to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I agree with all that, however in this world, nobody would *ever* talk about the function $i\sin(x)$ as anything other than a derivation step and "not real". That is, you are very clearly talking about functions $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @obscurans I'm not sure why you're objecting to this, because any $\Bbb{C}$-vector space can in particular be considered an $\Bbb{R}$-vector space, precisely because $\Bbb{R}$ is (field-isomorphic to) a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$. So, given the set of all functions $V:= \mathcal{F}(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{C})$ from $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$, you can definitely consider $V$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$, but it's also perfectly valid to consider it as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

To even make sense of the formula
$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$
you are fundamentally using complex numbers. Therefore constants are "any complex number", of which $i$ is one.

So when treating them as elements of a vector space of functions, $\sin(x)$ and $i\sin(x)$ are linearly dependent.

Note that you're running specific linear combinations
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\text{,}\quad\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
to recover a purely real function. This does not stop the fact that:

1. $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ are two linearly independent functions
2. Therefore you can recover two linearly independent functions by a change of basis
3. Even though these functions happen to be purely real for purely real arguments.

---

As the answer by **Fabio Lucchini** states, *if* you're considering functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ as a *real* vector space, then they are linearly independent.

However, this interpretation *does not make sense*. A vector space is where you can, for example, multiply elements by scalars. A function space $f:A\rightarrow B$ is, by the cardinal exponentiation interpretation, "a list of elements of $B$ indexed by elements of $A$". This means, for example,
$$(cf)(x)=c(f(x))$$
as an axiom. This multiplication is between $c$ and $f(x)\in B$. Therefore, using any scalar field other than $c\in B$ (in this case $\mathbb{C}$) *doesn't work*.